# pillow: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

i was working on my project at night, and after sleeping i just started getting this error all the time (i didn't touch the code before it broke, since i was sleeping), even tried going back to a previous stable version of the project and it keeps giving me the error

currently using pillow 8.3.2 and python 3.9.4

edit: i left it for a few days because i was busy, THEN IT JUST STARTED WORKING AGAIN FOR NO REASON, i'm sorry

````
  File "c:\Users\vitor\Desktop\music-tiermaker\app.py", line 9, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
  File "c:\Users\vitor\Desktop\music-tiermaker\vendor\PIL\Image.py", line 114, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (c:\Users\vitor\Desktop\music-tiermaker\vendor\PIL\__init__.py)```
````

Comment: Did this code really worked? Did you move something around? this `c:\Users\vitor\Desktop\music-tiermaker\vendor\PIL\Image.py` doesn't look like correct path for Pillow install.

Comment: the code did work, `/music-tiermaker/` is the parent folder where the main python script is located and all the libraries used are in the `/vendor/` subfolder

Comment: How did you install `Pillow` in the first place? The correct path will be under `site-packages` subfolder for your python installation.

Comment: i just used `pip install pillow -t "vendor_path"` because i didn't want to install it in my whole system, only on the project. which worked perfectly for weeks now, i could import pillow with no problems

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a issue with the relative import.
`from . import _imaging as core` where the . means current location.
First thing to check is if you are in the same location (on the command line) when you run your program.

Comment: they are in the same location, even after going to the stable version which worked 100% a few days ago i still get the error, here's a image to the [PIL folder](https://imgur.com/Vj4ppGo)